# How to resolve SLF4J, LOG4j2 issue in OSGi Application?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, log4j, osgi, slf4j

I have an OSGi Application that uses log4j 2.17.1, slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar, and slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar. The web server is running Tomcat 8.0.53. I'm getting this log4j2 error in the debug log when starting the application, and I'm not getting any logs although the application is running.

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Unable to retrieve WatchEventService from ClassLoader org.company.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.WebAppClassLoader@140c9f39
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.WatchManager.getEventServices(WatchManager.java:164)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.WatchManager.<init>(WatchManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:309)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager$PrivateManager.getContext(LogManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger(LogManager.java:89)
    at org.slf4j.reload4j.Reload4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Reload4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.reload4j.Reload4jServiceProvider.initialize(Reload4jServiceProvider.java:35)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:422)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:408)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils.<clinit>(LogUtils.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.<clinit>(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler.init(NamespaceHandler.java:27)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5363)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.company.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.startWebApp(TomcatWrapper.java:187)
    at org.company.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.prepareAllWebApps(TomcatWrapper.java:141)
    at org.company.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.startServer(TomcatWrapper.java:208)
    at org.company.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.Application.start(Application.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

I have org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util in the 'Export-Package' of the MANIFEST.MF file. Am I missing anything?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Dao Logging
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.company.dao.logging;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: org.company.dao.logging.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: bin/,
 lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar,
 lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar,
 lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar,
 lib/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar,
 lib/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar,
 lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
Export-Package: org.apache.commons.logging,
 org.apache.commons.logging.impl,
 org.apache.log4j,
 org.apache.log4j.bridge,
 org.apache.log4j.builders,
 org.apache.log4j.builders.appender,
 org.apache.log4j.builders.filter,
 org.apache.log4j.builders.layout,
 org.apache.log4j.builders.rewrite,
 org.apache.log4j.builders.rolling,
 org.apache.log4j.component.helpers,
 org.apache.log4j.config,
 org.apache.log4j.helpers,
 org.apache.log4j.jmx,
 org.apache.log4j.layout,
 org.apache.log4j.legacy.core,
 org.apache.log4j.or,
 org.apache.log4j.or.jms,
 org.apache.log4j.pattern,
 org.apache.log4j.rewrite,
 org.apache.log4j.spi,
 org.apache.log4j.varia,
 org.apache.log4j.xml,
 org.apache.logging.log4j,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.jeromq,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.nosql,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rewrite,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.arbiters,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.json,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.processor,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.validators,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.status,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jackson,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.internal,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.message,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.ssl,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.osgi,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.parser,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.internal,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.picocli,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.datetime,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.internal,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.message,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.simple,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.spi,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.status,
 org.apache.logging.log4j.util,
 org.apache.logging.slf4j,
 org.slf4j,
 org.slf4j.event,
 org.slf4j.helpers,
 org.slf4j.impl,
 org.slf4j.spi
```

*edit*
Updating log4j to 2.19.0 cleared the error but I'm getting messages like this now

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [bundleresource://8.fwk600746945:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

Here's all of the slf4j jars in my OSGi Bundle

```
root@8be4d7b90d60:/opt/core_server/default/plugins# find . -name "*slf4j*"
./com.company.platform.analytics.agent.model-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.analytics.agent.model-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.github.codegerm:org.cg.eventbus-1.0.9/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.github.codegerm:org.cg.eventbus-1.0.9/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.internal.agent-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.internal.agent-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.data.common-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.data.common-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.github.codegerm:org.cg.services.core-1.0.12/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.github.codegerm:org.cg.services.core-1.0.12/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.configuration.management:com.company.platform.configuration.management-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.configuration.management:com.company.platform.configuration.management-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./org.cg.dao.logging_1.0.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar
./org.cg.dao.logging_1.0.0/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.ingestion-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.ingestion-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.ingestion-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.14.jar
./com.company.platform.security-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-reload4j-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.security-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar
./com.company.platform.security-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.14.jar
```

*edit-2* Replacing log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar with log4j-slf4j2-impl-2.19.0.jar fixed the "SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found" issue.

Comment: Try version 2.19.0, it includes some workarounds to [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) limitations. BTW: SLF4J 2.x requires a [Service Loader Mediator](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.loader.html) like Apache Aries to be running, the Log4j2 API on the other hand has native OSGI support.

Comment: Upgrading Log4j2 to 2.19.0 cleared the error, but I'm still experiencing the no logs from Spring Service Beans (however the dependencies in the service beans are outputting logs). Edit my posted.

Comment: SLF4J 2.x requires updating your SLF4J bindings. Use `log4j-slf4j2-impl` instead of `log4j-slf4j-impl`.

Comment: That solves everything! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Piotr!

I had to upgrade log4j to 2.19.0 then use log4j-slf4j2-impl instead of log4j-slf4j-impl to bind with slf4j 2.0.3.

All is good now!